# Always On Availability Groups deleted when server rebooted

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I encountered an issue in which after a server reboot (reboot was not done gracefully), the AGs on that server were automatically deleted. The error encountered was the following:

AlwaysOn: WSFC AG integrity check failed for AG ‘PROD_DB1’ with error 41041, severity 16, state 0.
AlwaysOn: The local replica of availability group ‘PROD_DB1’ is being removed.
The instance of SQL Server failed to validate the integrity of the availability group configuration in the Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) store.

The only information that I found about this is in the below links:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/issue-replica-unexpectedly-dropped-in-availability-group/ba-p/318175

https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/03/17/sql-server-availability-group-missing-or-deleted-automatically

If anyone has ever encountered this, how can this be prevented if the servers reboots due to an issue? Do I need to maybe modify some group common properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mscs/group-common-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to prevent AGs from being deleted when maybe there is some sort of timeout or any other issue with the cluster DB?

Comment: Is your Windows cluster healthy? I've seen this happen when someone (or some automation) makes destructive changes to the WSFC, which causes the AG to only notice on server reboot when it validates the cluster & fails, which results in the AG being invalidated

Comment: Yes cluster is healthy with no errors, cluster validation also completed successfully.